# Loop operation with Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to make a storage system using Flutter and Firebase. When the user uploads a file to the application, the file is stored in Firebase Storage and a document is created for the file in Firestore and the file is displayed in the application. Likewise, when the user creates a folder, a document is created for the folder in Firestore, and if the user wants to upload a file to the folder, the "filePath" field in the file document is set as the doc id of the folder. Likewise, the user can create other folders within the folder. You can create folder B inside folder A and place the files there. Classic cloud storage logic. This is where I ran into a problem. Just as you create files and folders in the application, you can of course also delete them. I also want to set it so that when folders are deleted everything in them is deleted, but I haven't figured out how to cyclically delete other folders and files in subfolders within a folder. What I mean is this, for example, let's say you have folder A and inside this folder there is folder B, inside B there is folder C, and so on until folder Z. When the user wants to delete folder A, I want them to delete files starting from the innermost folder (in the example I gave, this is folder Z but it can go on forever), then go all the way to A and delete folder A last.

As I mentioned in the code example below, I wrote a code so that when folder A is deleted, the folders and files in it are deleted, but the code I wrote does not delete the data of the folders on Storage, it only deletes the documents in Firestore and prevents the folder from being viewed through the application. So it's not working properly.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

// Identify the folder containing the files
String path = 'cloud/files/$userId/$docId/';

//If there is a file in the folder, list it
bool hasFiles = await storage.ref(path).listAll().then((value) {
  return value.items.isNotEmpty;
});

// Delete files
if (hasFiles) {
  storage.ref(path).listAll().then((value) {
    // Dosyalar başarıyla silindi.
    for (var element in value.items) {
      storage.ref(element.fullPath).delete();
    }
  }, onError: (error) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  });

  //Delete Firestore data of subfolders within the folder
  QuerySnapshot querySnapFolders = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('folders').where('folderPath', isEqualTo: docId).get();
  QueryDocumentSnapshot docFolders = querySnapFolders.docs[0];
  DocumentReference docRefFolders = docFolders.reference;
  docRefFolders.delete();

  //Delete Firestore data of files in the folder
  QuerySnapshot querySnapFiles = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cloud').where('filePath', isEqualTo: docId).get();
  QueryDocumentSnapshot docFiles = querySnapFiles.docs[0];
  DocumentReference docRefFiles = docFiles.reference;
  docRefFiles.delete();
}

//Delete the folder's own Firestore data and complete the process
QuerySnapshot querySnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('folders').where('docId', isEqualTo: docId).get();
QueryDocumentSnapshot doc = querySnap.docs[0];
DocumentReference docRef = doc.reference;
docRef.delete().whenComplete(() => Navigator.pop(context));
```

I should mention that I store the subfolders in the same location as the main folder in the repository. All folders are located at the "cloud/files/$userId/$docId" location specified in the code, using their own document IDs. I display the folders in the Firestore documents by setting the "folderPath" field to be the doc id of the main folder. The folder path of each folder is equal to the id of the folder it is in. The folderPath value of folder B is the id of A.

The issue seems a bit complicated. I'm sorry if there are parts I couldn't explain. If you have any questions, I will be happy to answer them. I am waiting for your support.

Comment: Did you already step through the code you shared in a debugger? So: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. If you do this, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: There is no error in the code I specified. It just doesn't quite do what I want. I'm asking how I can update the code according to the request I specified.

Answer (score 1):

To recursively delete folder, you need to define this method:

```
Future<void> recursiveDelete(Reference ref) async {
    final listResult = await ref.listAll();
    // delete all files
    await Future.wait(listResult.items.map((e) => e.delete()));
    // recursively delete sub folders
    await Future.wait(listResult.prefixes.map(recursiveDelete));
    // delete folder itself
    await ref.delete();
}
```

Call above method:

```
try {
    await recursiveDelete(storage.ref(path));
} on Exception {
    Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

However, please bear in mind that listAll() can potentially consume too much memory if your folder has too many items. Consider using list() with pagination.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I want.

Comment: I see, so your problem is recursively deletion. I've updated the answer.